# Remove duplicates from list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Given the list of lists  `duplicates = [[1,1,1],[2],[1,1,1]]`

How to remove the duplicates so that the result is `[[2]]`?

Comment: Being very new to Haskell is actually no excuse at all not to try at least sometime.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Data.MultiSet> [a | (a, 1) <- toOccurList (fromList [[1,1,1],[2],[1,1,1]])]
[[2]]
```