# Is there a function in Haskell that would work like 'uniqueBy'?

Tags: list, haskell, unique

I need a function that could be called *`uniqueBy`* that would **remove *all*** elements in a list of tuples that have the same *`snd`* value, without keeping even one of them as `nubBy` would.
For example,

```
uniqueBy [(1,1),(2,1)]
```

should return `[]`, whereas

```
uniqueBy [(1,1),(1,1),(1,2)]
```

would return `[(1,2)]`.

Sadly this function *`uniqueBy`* does not exist and I can't seem to find an alternative function or a way to implement it myself, although I'm sure there has to be an easy way.

Comment: This isn't going to be a simple application of a library function.  Though it's isn't super complicated, you will need to do some amount of the logic yourself.

Comment: should `uniqueBy [(1,1),(2,1)]` return `[(1,1)]` or `[]`? by analogy it is the former, but from your description it is the latter. Which is it?

Comment: @WillNess it should return []

Comment: but the answer below does not do that. it would return the first one. perhaps you should edit your question with the clarification.

Comment: One way is to run your list through `sort` ,then `groupBy`, then `filter` and `map` to keep only such groups that have more than one elements in them and turn those resulting groups each into just the head element's `snd` field. now you have the list of `snd` values to get rid of the tuples by, so do another `filter` of the original list, with `elem` in the predicate.

Comment: another, done with list comprehensions, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64942087/checking-for-all-elements-in-a-set-in-haskell-using-syntactic-sugar).

Comment: [third option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343937/849891), using `Data.MultiSet.fromList` and then `Data.MultiSet.toOccurList` with `map fst . filter ((==1) . snd)` or the equivalent list comprehesion.

Comment: [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64977408/849891) based on the sort--group--filter--map approach has since been added to the entry linked above. it answers this question.

Answer (score 2):

The [**`Data.List`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) has a [**`nubBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy) function. You thus can use this like:

```
import Data.Function(on)
import Data.List(nubBy)

uniqueOnSnd :: Eq b => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
uniqueOnSnd = nubBy ((==) `on` snd)
```

For example:

```
Main> uniqueOnSnd  [(4,1), (5,2), (3,1), (2,0)]
[(4,1),(5,2),(2,0)]
```

`nubBy` takes, just like `nub`, *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time. So in case you can order the elements, it is more efficient to first order and *then* perform a uniqness filter, like:

```
import Data.Function(on)
import Data.List(sortBy)

nubOrderBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
nubOrderBy cmp = go . sortBy cmp
    where go (x1:xs) = x1 : go (dropWhile ((EQ ==) . cmp x1) xs)
          go [] = []

uniqueOnSnd :: Ord b => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
uniqueOrdOnSnd = nubOrderBy (compare `on` snd)
```

A disadvantage of this is that it can not work with infinite lists, and furthermore that the order will not be preserved, but here w thus filter out duplicates in *O(n* log *n)*.

Comment: [`nubOrdOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html#v:nubOrdOn) from `containers` has the advantage of preserving the original order of elements.

Comment: @sjakobi: yes, this makes use of a `Set`. I wanted to provide a solution without using data structures from other packages. Of course one can implement a (tree)set themselves and indeed boost the member check. This will also work with infinite lists, since then you simply use a `Set` and update it while enumerating over the list.

Comment: [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944978/is-there-a-nubby-analogy-for-unique-in-haskell#comment114832799_64944978) the OP wants to remove all duplicates, leaving not one of them in the result.

Comment: the OP already mentions nubBy in the title and say they want something else.